# Posting to both Facebook pages & Twitter accounts

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, twitter

We're successfully posting to Facebook pages through the Facebook API - both as the page admins using their individual access tokens, as well as the pages themselves using the manage_pages permission.

We're trying to set things up so that the posts also go to twitter accounts. The Facebook pages in question were previously manually linked via the admins to the corresponding twitter accounts via facebook.com/twitter. However although manual posts on the facebook pages cross-post to twitter ok, the programmatic posts via the api (whether as the page admin or the page) don't show up there.

Is this a bug or intentional feature? Any workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Just include the header file #import "Twitter/Twitter.h" and add the framework Twitter.framework in the project..

and add the below lines for a button action

TWTweetComposeViewController *tweeter = [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init]; [tweeter setInitialText:@"your score"]; [self presentModalViewController:tweeter animated:YES];

That all.. ur score will be posted...

If u want to add picture use [tweeter addImage:image ]; If u want to add url use [tweeter addUrl:@" your url"];

Comment: Not sure I understood any of that, sorry... we are using the PHP SDK by the way; it looks like the above is something different...

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the [Twitter API](https://dev.twitter.com/) to post to Twitter directly.

Comment: ...agreed, was just wondering if there was a way to do this apart from rewriting a separate app for the twitter api...